trying to create test classes in salesforce apex and pass with 100% code coverage
Salesforce Apex, Test class:
I am trying to create a TestClass and attain 100% code coverage in apex for a batch processing script. The class that I am testing looks like this:
    public class UpdateContractStatusBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Schedulable {
        public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id, Status__c, SBQQ__RenewalForecast__c FROM Contract WHERE Status__c = \'Activated\' AND Legacy_Contract__c = false';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
        }
        public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contract> scope) {
        if (scope.size()==0){
           return;
        }

        List<Contract> contractsToUpdate = new List<Contract>();
        List<Database.SaveResult> results;

        try {
            for(Contract con : scope) {
                con.Status__c = 'Renewal Forecasted';
                con.SBQQ__RenewalForecast__c = true;
                contractsToUpdate.add(con);
            }

            results = Database.update(contractsToUpdate, false);
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('Exception in batch execute: ' + e.getMessage());
        }

        for (Database.SaveResult sr : results) {
            if(!sr.isSuccess()) {
                for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                    System.debug('Error updating contract Id: ' + sr.getId() + ' - ' + err.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }

        for (Database.SaveResult sr : results) {
            if(!sr.isSuccess()) {
                 for(Database.Error err : sr.getErrors()) {
                      System.debug('Error updating contact ID: ' + sr.getId() + ' - ' + err.getMessage());
        }
       }
      }
     }

     public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
     }

     public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
           Database.execueBatch(new UpdateContractStatusBatch());
     }
}

And here's my test class so far that achieves 76% code coverage:
@isTest
private class UpdateContractsStatusBatchTest{

    @isTest
    static void testBatch(){
        // Create admin user
        Profile adminProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator' LIMIT 1];
        User adminUser = new User(
            Alias = 'admin',
            Email = 'admindarktrace@testuser.com',
            EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
            LastName = 'Admin',
            LanguageLocalKey = 'en_US',
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
            ProfileId = adminProfile.Id,
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
            UserName = 'oliver-admindarktrace@testuser.com',
            ByPassValidation__c = true
        );
        insert adminUser;

        // Run the test as athe admin user
        System.runAs(adminUser) {
            // create product
            Product2 sp = new Product2(
                Name = 'Test Subscription',
                IsActive = true,
                SBQQ__PricingMethod__c = 'List',
                SBQQ__SubscriptionPricing__c = 'Fixed Price',
                SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c = 12,
                Status__c = 'Draft'
            );
            insert sp;

            Id pbid = Test.getStandardPriceBookId();
            PricebookEntry spbe = new PricebookEntry(Product2Id = sp.id, Pricebook2Id = pbid, UnitPrice = 1, IsActive = true);
            insert spbe;

            // Create Account
            Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account', BillingCity = 'St Albans');
            insert a;

            //Create Opps
            Opportunity o = new Opportunity(
                AccountId = a.Id,
                Name = 'Test Opps',
                StageName = 'Qualification',
                CloseDate = Date.today(),
                Pricebook2Id = pbid,
                CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD',
                Deal_Type__c = 'Direct',
                Direct_Customer_Sales_Channel__c = 'Direct'
            );
            insert o;

            // Create Quote
            SBQQ__Quote___c q = new SBQQ__Quote___c(
                SBQQ__Account__c = a.Id,
                SBQQ__Opportunity2__c = o.Id,
                SBQQ__Type__c = 'Quote',
                SBQQ__Primary__c = true,
                SBQQ__Pricebook__c = pbid,
                SBQQ__StartDate__c = Date.today(),
                SBQQ__EndDate__c = Date.today() + 365,
                Deal_Type__c = 'Direct',
                Sales_Channel__c = 'Direct',
                SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c = 12,
                SBQQ__Renewal__c = 8
            );
            insert q;

            // Create Quote Line
            SBQQ__QuoteLine__c sql = new SBQQ__QuoteLine__c (
                SBQQ__Quote__c = q.Id,
                SBQQ__Product__c = sp.Id,
                SBQQ__Quanity__c = 1,
                SBQQ__SubscriptionPricing__c = 'Fixed Price',
                SBQQ__ProductSubscriptionType__c = 'Renewable',
                SBQQ__SubscriptionType__c = 'Renewable',
                SBQQ__DefaultSubscriptionTerm__c = 12,
                SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c = 12,
                SBQQ__StartDate__c = Date.today()
            );
            insert sql;

            // Create Legacy_Contract__c = true
            Contract c1 = new Contract(
                AccountId = a.Id,
                SBQQ__Opportunity__c = o.Id,
                SBQQ__Quote__c = q.Id,
                Status__c = 'Draft',
                StartDate__c = Date.today(),
                ContractTerm = 12,
                Legacy_Contract__c = true,
                SBQQ__PreserveBundlesStructureUponRenewals__c = true
            );
            insert c1;


            // Create Legacy_Contract__c = false
            Contract c2 = new Contract(
                AccountId = a.Id,
                SBQQ__Opportunity__c = o.Id,
                SBQQ__Quote__c = q.Id,
                Status__c = 'Draft',
                StartDate__c = Date.today(),
                ContractTerm = 12,
                Legacy_Contract__c = false,
                SBQQ__PreserveBundlesStructureUponRenewals__c = true
            );
            insert c2;


            //Create Subscription
            SBQQ__Subscription__c = new SBQQ__Subscription__c(
                SBQQ__Account__c = a.Id,
                SBQQ__Contract__c = c2.Id,
                SBQQ__Product__c = sp.Id,
                SBQQ__QuoteLine__c = sql.Id,
                SBQQ__Quanity__c = 1,
                SBQQ__ListPrice__c = 1,
                SBQQ__NetPrice__c = 1,
                SBQQ__CustomerPrice__c = 1,
                SBQQ__RenewalQuantity__c = 1
            );
            insert s;

            // Enque the batch
            Test.startTest();
            UpdateContractsStatusBatch batch = new UpdateContractsStatusBatch();
            Database.executeBatch(batch);
            Test.stopTest();

            // Verify that the contracts were updated
            List<Contract> updateContractsC1 = [SELECT Id, Status__c, SBQQ__RenewalForecast__c FROM Contract WHERE Id = :c2.Id];
            System.assertEquals('Renewal Forecasted', updatedContractsC1[0].Status__c, 'Contract is updated');
            System.assertEquals(true, updatedContractsC1[0].SBQQ__RenewalForecast__c, 'Renewal Forecast must be true');


// Verify that the contracts were updated
            List<Contract> updateContractsC2 = [SELECT Id, Status__c, SBQQ__RenewalForecast__c FROM Contract WHERE Id = :c2.Id];
            System.assertEquals('Renewal Forecasted', updatedContractsC2[0].Status__c, 'Contract is updated');
            System.assertEquals(true, updatedContractsC2[0].SBQQ__RenewalForecast__c, 'Renewal Forecast must be true');
        }
    }
}

The Lines that are not being covered in the class are:
Line 10:    Return;

Line 24:    } catch (Exception e){

Line 30:    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
                  Database.executeBatch(new UpdateContractStatusBatch());

100% code coverages is what I am after. Thanks in advance!!

if (scope.size()==0){
    return;
}

This is unreachable code. If there would be zero records remaining - it wouldn't even call execute() that last time. Delete it.
try {
    for(Contract con : scope) {
        con.Status__c = 'Renewal Forecasted';
        con.SBQQ__RenewalForecast__c = true;
        contractsToUpdate.add(con);
    }

    results = Database.update(contractsToUpdate, false);

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.debug('Exception in batch execute: ' + e.getMessage());
}

This is pretty unreachable too. You're using the Database.update version that doesn't throw exceptions. In more complex code you could have hit some math errors (division by zero or stuff like "5 + null = exception thrown") but what we see looks pretty safe.
These debugs are pretty weak. Once you're past initial development phase I'd delete them and read up about Database.RaisesPlatformEvents.
public void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

You can cover this by calling the method explicitly, new UpdateContractStatusBatch().execute(null); or check "Testing the Apex Scheduler" in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm
